# Bind object literal to different attributes of a button-tag

Tags: angularjs

- I want to bind the buttons text/caption to the value of the property 
  'schoolclassCode'
- I want to bind the buttons background-color to the    value of the
  property 'background'

How can I do both?

```
this.schoolclassCodeColors = [
    { background: 'yellow', schoolclassCode: 'Sports5a'},
    { background: 'green', schoolclassCode: 'Music3a'}
];
this.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor = this.schoolclassCodeColors[0]

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled"
        ng-style="{{activeStep.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor}}" >
    {{activeStep.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor}}<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: You want a button to have two backgrounds and two texts?

Comment: No. the ng-style should be for the background-color. The other for the text. aka schoolclasscode. I want to have the button displaying 'Sports5a' in yellow background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign those variables to the scope so it becomes available in the template:

```
this.schoolclassCodeColors = [
    { background: 'yellow', schoolclassCode: 'Sports5a'},
    { background: 'green', schoolclassCode: 'Music3a'}
];
this.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor = this.schoolclassCodeColors[0];
$scope.activeStep = this.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor;

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled"
        ng-style="{background: activeStep.background}"" >
    {{activeStep.schoolclassCode}}<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: oh... How I start hating angular... there is no scope in my factory which holds the above data. And I no I can not inject it but I can not put my logic within a controller because I would need many of them (wizard with steps) then I loose the preserve state etc... argh... really start hating it.

Comment: That's cool, the scope shouldn't be in the factory. Use factory to return there values, and assign them to the scope in the controller. I'll write you an example.

Comment: Dont do it. I know. Its not a solution for mee.

Comment: The activeStep is already bound to the $scope inside the MainWizController where all 3 steps are bound.

Comment: The button is not yellow :P

Comment: I used your code to adapt to mine and it works that the text and color is bound and can be switched BUT... there is a html parsing error in the UI (not in the browser console). Right before the button is this: style="background: " Why is the the 2nd double quote? Its not in my html.

Comment: Thats the full LoC:                                      style="background: {{activeStep.selectedSchoolclassCodeColor.background}}">

Comment: Ok everything is fine forget my last comment I had old code in the html... :P